# Convert a list into a data frame

Tags: r

I have tried many, many codes but I cannot convert this list into a data frame. I'm not sure if it's a list of lists or a bunch of character string vectors (except for a couple columns - like the age column), but I'd really appreciate a data frame for easier manipulation. Here is kind of what it looks like: (we'll call it favs)

```
Name        Age        Favorite color      Favorite ice cream     ...
John        35         Yellow              Vanilla
Abby        12         Blue                Chocolate
Max         67         White               Strawberry
```

Anyway, the list has 2,557 rows and 470 columns so, it's a little too big to convert column by column. I want it to look the way it already does, but as a data frame with each column as a column, not a character string. Here are codes I've already tried

```
data.frame(favs)
as_data_frame(favs)
list2df(favs)
list_df2df(favs)
matrix(unlist(favs), nr0w=length(favs), byrow=TRUE)
do.call(rbind, favs)
do.call(cbind, favs)
```

Nothing is working. Please help.

Comment: can you share what does the output of str(favs) looks like

Comment: As presented, I would expect `as.data.frame` to work, but it's really difficult. As @SmitM suggested, please edit your question with the output from `str(favs)` (or a small relevant portion of it, if the output is unwieldy).

Comment: Ok when I do str(favs) it says it's a data frame but when I say typeof(favs) it says it's a list. Here is what it looks like: 'data.frame' :     2557 obs. of 470 variables: and each variable is a factor with differing levels

Comment: `typeof(favs)` returning `"list"` does **not** mean that it is not a df, since df's are lists. Furthermore, the output of `str` shows it's a df.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ok, so you don't think it's anything to worry about?

Comment: Apparently not, no.

Comment: Is there something else (besides `typeof`) that suggests it it not behaving as a `data.frame`? If not ... know that a `matrix` is effectively a 2+ dim `vector`, all the same `class` (e.g., `logical`, `numeric`, `integer`, `character`); while a `data.frame` is a `list` where each column can be a different class from the others. (One important property of `data.frame` that makes it a special-case `list` is that all of its components are the same length.)